# Android - No implementation found for native method, even after calling loadLibrary

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use the [liboqs-java library](https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs-java). liboqs is a C library that can be built for Android, and liboqs-java is a Java wrapper that relies on liboqs.

What I've done so far:

1. Copied the `c/` folder and `java/` [folder from liboqs-java](https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs-java/tree/master/src/main) to my app's `src/main/` folder.
2. Compiled the liboqs C library for x86_64 Android using the NDK. I copied the `liboqs.so` to my app's `src/main/jniLibs/` folder.

What my file structure looks like now:

[image: Android Studio file tree with c, java, jniLibs folders]

In `Common.java` from the liboqs-java wrapper, I called loaded the `liboqs.so` library, which does not cause any errors (if the library is not found, an error is thrown by Java):

```
public static void loadNativeLibrary() {
        System.out.println("Loading liboqs.so for: " + Build.CPU_ABI + "...");
        System.loadLibrary("oqs"); // This string is transformed to "liboqs.so"
}
```

However in my `MainActivity.java`, I attempt to use some of the code from the Java wrapper. Here's what I see in logcat:

```
2021-01-19 10:32:23.388 10501-10501/io.trustwave.polarisclientapp I/System.out: Loading liboqs.so for: x86_64...
2021-01-19 10:32:23.389 10501-10501/io.trustwave.polarisclientapp E/olarisclientap: No implementation found for int org.openquantumsafe.Sigs.max_number_sigs() (tried Java_org_openquantumsafe_Sigs_max_1number_1sigs and Java_org_openquantumsafe_Sigs_max_1number_1sigs__)
2021-01-19 10:32:23.389 10501-10501/io.trustwave.polarisclientapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-01-19 10:32:23.390 10501-10501/io.trustwave.polarisclientapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: io.trustwave.polarisclientapp, PID: 10501
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for int org.openquantumsafe.Sigs.max_number_sigs() (tried Java_org_openquantumsafe_Sigs_max_1number_1sigs and Java_org_openquantumsafe_Sigs_max_1number_1sigs__)
        at org.openquantumsafe.Sigs.max_number_sigs(Native Method)
        at org.openquantumsafe.Sigs.get_supported_sigs(Sigs.java:61)
        at io.trustwave.polarisclientapp.MainActivity.testOQSSignatureGeneration(MainActivity.java:34)
        at io.trustwave.polarisclientapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2021-01-19 10:32:23.413 10501-10501/io.trustwave.polarisclientapp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10501 SIG: 9
```

From what I know, the issue is that the `.c` and `.h` files are not linking to the liboqs-java `.java` files, which causes the "No implementation found for..." issue. `System.loadLibrary("oqs")` works fine.

I have not modified any Android project files or done anything to link the library. I don't know where to start doing that, or if I even need to. I noticed the Android documentation suggests calling the `c/` folder `cpp/`, but that had no effect.

Android emulator version: API 30, x86_64

Comment: have you added this inside gradle ?    ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }

Comment: mostly these libraries doesnt work on emulator I guess, try to run on real device.

Comment: @NehaK I'm not sure where to put this. Should this be in the root build.gradle or app build.gradle? And which block do I place it in? Thanks for replying

Comment: app one.. inside defaultConfig {

Comment: Unfortunately that had no effect.

Comment: have you tried in real device?

Comment: As I remember when I was doing the same, it was not used to work in emulator

Comment: That C code isn't going to be built automatically. You'll have to write a makefile, or find a pre-written one.

Comment: Shouldn't the C code already be built, since I included `liboqs.so`? There is a `CMakeLists.txt` from the liboqs C library, where can I place it?

Answer (score 0):

I have what may be a partial answer for you as I am building a library in Dart for use in the Flutter framework.

First file structure. If it does not already exist, add a jniLibs folder. Inside that include folders for each abi.

[image: Folders for Android]

If it does not already exist, add a CMakeLists.txt file and include the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
add_library(liboqs SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(liboqs PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/liboqs.so)
```

Make sure you have the following in your `build.gradle` file.

```
android {

    externalNativeBuild{
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

For the flutter framework, I had to register the C functions using Dart::ffi. The Java Library may already have done that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After using the externalNativeBuild and adding a CMakeLists.txt, the app compiles. However, it crashes on the same line of code (creating a new signature). The error message is now instead "JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x702937bf1c" and "Dumping all threads without mutator lock held". Here is my crash log, do you have any ideas? https://gist.github.com/taimoorgit/a89e978c7a7989254e7a0237954cd6ca

Comment: My first suggestion is try to rebuild without Rainbow (i.e. change the android build script to include -DOQS_ENABLE_SIG_RAINBOW=OFF). Another challenge I encountered had to do with Mac systems requiring 64 bit, so do make sure you are building for x86_64 if you are using an emulator.

Comment: All in all, the error appears to be related to some mismatch between the Java nested Class `signature_details` and the struct in the C code.

Comment: Thanks again. I compiled liboqs again for Android successfully with rainbow signatures disabled. Now when I run the app the rainbow signatures don't show up as being enabled, so I know that worked fine. However, I still get the exact same error with 0x702937bf1c. I'm starting to think this is an issue with liboqs-java itself? Also, using the CMakeLists.txt file had no effect (I added the externalNativeBuild to my build.gradle file).

Comment: If possible, can you post some source code of getting liboqs to work on Android via Flutter? I understand it might take too long or might be confidential, in which case I understand. I ask because I want to rule out any possibilities that I'm not linking liboqs correctly using Android or my build scripts. Thanks again

Comment: Yes -- definitely possible, although the state of the sample code includes a seg fault right now. (Sorry for the comment as chat, but I cannot figure out how to send a private message.)

Comment: No worries, and thank you. Please take your time, the source code would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Got it working without Seg faults finally.  x86_64 Android only for now (problems with Mac Emulators running non-64).  The modest test suit will only work for mac.  Leave an issue if you are having problems, and PRs always welcome! https://github.com/greebie/liboqs_flutter